OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'invalid scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
So basically , I am building a Chrome Extension using vanilla javascript for outlook. In that extension I have to fetch the email of currently logged in user. I have registered my app on Azure , got the client ID , added the neccessary permissions like openId , profile , User.Read , User.Mail in app ,  added neccessary scopes but Still I am not getting the identity token.
**
manifest.json**
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Plugin for Outlook",
    "description": "Base Level Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
      "default_icon": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "contextMenus",
      "activeTab",
      "scripting",
      "storage",
      "identity"
      
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/*",
      "https://ccqrs034g7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/*"
    ],

    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "oauth2": {
        "client_id":"my id",
        "scopes": [
          "openid", "email", "profile" , "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" 
     ]
      },
    "content_scripts":[
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js":["contentScript.js"] 
        }
    ]
  }

background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log("hello");

  if (message.action === "getEmail") {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !token) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        return;
      }

      fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((userInfo) => {
          const data = message.data;
          console.log(data);

          // Sending Data to backend
         
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    });
  }
  return true;
});



Are you seeing any error?

The error occurs because Google Chrome doesn't understand what you specified in the scope. The oauth2 key in manifest.json is for authenticating users through Google. You can read more about it in this official guide.
chrome.identity.getAuthToken, is also designed to get a token from Google. To implement authentication in non-Google services you need to use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow.
Here's the sequence of how Non-Google account authentication works.
